# How to replace (not add) properties during Import in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, import, shopware, dbal

We are using Shopware 6.3.5 and want to replace properties during import (update) of products.

We specifiy to product ID and the list or property UUIDs (in the column `properties`)

Currently, those get added to the existing properties in the database.

This seems to be due to the behavior of the `upsert` call during the import.

How can this be changed?

We tried this:

DI:

```
<argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
```

Method:

```
class ImportSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent::class => 'onImportExportBeforeImportRecord'
        ];
    }

    public function onImportExportBeforeImportRecord(ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent $event)
    {
        $this->productRepository->update([
            [
                'id' => $event->getRecord()['id'],
                'property_ids' => null,
            ]
        ], $event->getContext());
    }
}
```

But this update statement causes a `\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\WriteTypeIntendException` in `\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\WriteCommandQueue::ensureIs`

I am also wondering what this WriteCommandQueue does and if it is too lower level what I am trying to do?

Additionally I am wondering if property_ids is the right field to change or actually I have to clear up the product_property table for that import row?

*EDIT*

Next I tried this

DI:

```
<argument type="service" id="product_property.repository"/>
```

Method:

```
    public function onImportExportBeforeImportRecord(ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent $event)
    {
        $existing = $this->productPropertryRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productId', $event->getRecord()['id'])),
            $event->getContext()
        );
        $entities = $existing->getEntities();
        foreach($entities as $entity) {
            $this->productPropertryRepository->delete([
                [
                    'productId' => $event->getRecord()['id'],
                    'optionId' => $entity->get('optionId')
                ]
            ], $event->getContext());
        }
    }
```

But I get a

`Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Exception\MappingEntityClassesException` with

`Mapping definition neither have entities nor collection.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search method does not work on Mapping Definitions. You can use `searchIds` to get the ids and call the delete like you have.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Shyim's answer, this works:

```
    public function onImportExportBeforeImportRecord(ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent $event)
    {
        $existing = $this->productPropertyRepository->searchIds(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productId', $event->getRecord()['id'])),
            $event->getContext()
        );

        foreach($existing->getIds() as $id) {
            if (in_array($id['property_group_option_id'], ($event->getRecord()['properties'] ?? [] ))) {
                continue;
            }

            $this->productPropertyRepository->delete([
                [
                    'productId' => $event->getRecord()['id'],
                    'optionId' => $id['property_group_option_id']
                ]
            ], $event->getContext());
        }
    }
```

Note: This deletes all current properties, a more sophistic solution might be to only specific properties (for example by supplying a list of names in the import) or have a positive/negative list with properties that should be cleared or kept.